# python pandas read_csv issue certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1123)

Tags: python, pandas, ssl

I'm doing the machine learning study. Two days ago, when I was testing the Perceptron model, the pandas method
***pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data', header=None)***
works fine, I can get the Iris matrix data. But today when I try the adaline model, the getting data statement doesn't change, read_csv gives me error below:

[image]

Comment: The problem is with the site you are trying to connect, the certificate of ```archive.ics.uci.edu``` is self signed, you can ignore it.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original). See why [an image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: the question is fine, i don't know why you unvoted the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

url = "THE URL"
s = requests.get(url).content
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
```

Comment: This works! But why the statement in my question worked two days ago

Comment: The problem is with certificate, maybe you were using http instead of https, or the certificate was valid and today it is not.